# Caffeine indicator won't enable

Tags: caffeine

When I right click on the caffeine indicator and click activate nothing happens. It has worked fine up to now.

I'm running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

I tried terminating the processes (caffeine and caffeine indicator) then re-running them, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add your version of Ubuntu

Comment: I recommend reporting this to the App Developer....http://launchpad.net/caffeine Edit: Actually already reported...https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1768658 although they tagged it as invalid. Perhaps you can make a better report.